# Conditional step/stage in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

How do you run a build step/stage only if building a specific branch?

For example, run a deployment step only if the branch is called `deployment`, leaving everything else the same.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

Doing the same in declarative pipeline syntax, below are few examples:

```
stage('master-branch-stuff') {
    when {
        branch 'master'
    }
    steps {
        echo 'run this stage - ony if the branch = master branch'
    }
}
```

---

```
stage('feature-branch-stuff') {
    when {
        branch 'feature/*'
    }
    steps {
        echo 'run this stage - only if the branch name started with feature/'
    }
}
```

---

```
stage('expression-branch') {
    when {
        expression {
            return env.BRANCH_NAME != 'master';
        }
    }
    steps {
        echo 'run this stage - when branch is not equal to master'
    }
}
```

---

```
stage('env-specific-stuff') {
    when { 
        environment name: 'NAME', value: 'this' 
    }
    steps {
        echo 'run this stage - only if the env name and value matches'
    }
}
```

More effective ways coming up -
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41187

Also look at -
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when

---

The directive `beforeAgent true` can be set to avoid spinning up an agent to run the conditional, if the conditional doesn't require git state to decide whether to run:

```
when { beforeAgent true; expression { return isStageConfigured(config) } }
```

[Release post](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2018/04/09/whats-in-declarative/) and [docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when)

---

**UPDATE**
New WHEN Clause
REF: https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/04/09/whats-in-declarative

> equals - Compares two values - strings, variables, numbers, booleans -
> and returns true if they’re equal. I’m honestly not sure how we missed
> adding this earlier! You can do "not equals" comparisons using the not
> { equals ... } combination too.
>
> changeRequest - In its simplest form, this will return true if this
> Pipeline is building a change request, such as a GitHub pull request.
> You can also do more detailed checks against the change request,
> allowing you to ask "is this a change request against the master
> branch?" and much more.
>
> buildingTag - A simple condition that just checks if the Pipeline is
> running against a tag in SCM, rather than a branch or a specific
> commit reference.
>
> tag - A more detailed equivalent of buildingTag, allowing you to check
> against the tag name itself.

Comment: can I use this for the post build actions?

Comment: I find Jenkins spins up the specified agent even if the `when{}` condition evaluates to false. :(

Comment: @Trejkaz you can now use `beforeAgent true` to avoid that

Comment: @NickJones indeed, `beforeAgent` is now a workaround for that.

Answer (score 61):

Just use `if` and `env.BRANCH_NAME`, example:

```
    if (env.BRANCH_NAME == "deployment") {                                          
        ... do some build ...
    } else {                                   
        ... do something else ...
    }
```

Comment: if should  be before stage or after ?

Comment: Before stage, stages can be inside if branches

Comment: don't think the placement actually matters

Comment: I can't get this work with a declarative pipeline.  Does this work with declarative pipelines?  WorkflowScript: 9: Expected a stage @ line 9, column 9. if (env.BRANCH_NAME == "deployment") { WorkflowScript: 8: No stages specified @ line 8, column 5.  stages {

Comment: See Chandan Nayak's answer: `when { branch 'master' }`

Comment: this only works in scripted pipelines. for declarative pipelines, you should use script {} inside the step.

Comment: what's the diference between both?
Mine is not working, it skip both stages even when the branch is Master.

Answer (score 14):

I'm adding this answer to explicitly mention using a condition in a *step* in contrast to a *stage*, both within *declarative pipelines*.

## Condition in a stage of a declarative pipeline

As already shown by @Chandan Nayak and others, this can be done based on `when` as in

```
stage('myConditionalStage') {
    when {
        branch 'myBranch'
    }
    steps {
        echo 'triggered by myBranch'
    }
}
```

So the stage `myConditionalStage` will only be run if triggered by a push to `myBranch`.

## Condition in a step of a declarative pipeline's stage

If you however need a condition within the steps section of a stage, you can use Groovy syntax (`if/else` in this case) that is used in *Scripted pipelines*. In case of a *Declarative pipeline* you have to put it into a `script` block as follows:

```
stage('myStage') {
    steps {
        echo 'within myStage'
        script {
            if (env.BRANCH_NAME == "myBranch") {
                echo 'triggered by myBranch'
            } else {
                echo 'triggered by something else'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For a *Scripted pipeline*, you can use it without the `script` block as shown by @Krzysztof Krasoń

Answer (score 8):

According to other answers I am adding the parallel stages scenario:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('some parallel stage') {
            parallel {
                stage('parallel stage 1') {
                    when {
                      expression { ENV == "something" }
                    }
                    steps {
                        echo 'something'
                    }
                }
                stage('parallel stage 2') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'something'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to have a condition in step? I am using if else in step. I have parallel stage for datacenter 1 and datacenter 2. Then in each datacenter, I have to either install or uninstall depending on option chosen

Answer (score -1):

I created more nested stages as follows:

```
    pipeline {
     
      // Agent To Run On
      agent none
    
      stages {

   
    // Processing OpenCV Optimizer
    stage('OpenCV Processing'){

      when {
          expression { inputOptimizer == "OpenCV DNN" }
      }


      stages {

        // Checkout and Compile stage
        stage('SCM Checkout & Build'){

          parallel {

            stage('Test On Windows') {
                agent {
                    label "Stagging-Node"
                }
                steps {
                    echo "first stage"
                }
            }//Test On Windows

            stage('Test On Linux') {
                agent {
                    label "Stagging-Node"
                }
                steps {
                    echo "second stage"
                }

            }//Test On Linux

            stage('Testing '){
              agent {
                    label "Stagging-Node"
                }
                steps {
                    echo "second dddd"
                }
            }//Testing

          }

        }

        // Docker Build
        stage("Docker Build"){
      
          steps {

            echo "Build stage"

          }
        
        }

      }

    }


    // Processing OpenVino Optimizer
    stage('OpenVino Processing'){

      when {
          expression { inputOptimizer == "OpenVino CPU Yolov7" }
      }


      stages {

        // Checkout and Compile stage
        stage('SCM Checkout & Build'){

          parallel {

            stage('Test On Windows') {
                agent {
                    label "Stagging-Node"
                }
                steps {
                    echo "first stage"
                }
            }//Test On Windows

            stage('Test On Linux') {
                agent {
                    label "Stagging-Node"
                }
                steps {
                    echo "second stage"
                }

            }//Test On Linux

            stage('Testing '){
              agent {
                    label "Stagging-Node"
                }
                steps {
                    echo "second dddd"
                }
            }//Testing

          }

        }

        // Docker Build
        stage("Docker Build"){
      
          steps {

            echo "Build stage"

          }
        
        }

      }

    }
      
  }//end of stages

}//end of pipeline
```