# Jenkins skip some stage if variable contain in list

Tags: jenkins

Can i do pass some stage when some variable contain in list .

```
`def list = ['a', 'b', 'c']`
```

`String result = list.join(",")`
   `enter code here`def value = 'a'
   `enter code here`value.toString()
   `enter code here`def valid = list.findAll { it.contains("$value") }
   `enter code here`valid.toString()
   `enter code here`println valid
   `enter code here`println list
   `enter code here`if (valid == value ) { 
    `enter code here`     //If the condition is true print the following statement 
    `enter code here`     println("Go Ahead"); 
     `enter code here` } else { 
      `enter code here`   //If the condition is false print the following `enter code here`statement 
      `enter code here`  println("Stopped"); 
   `enter code here` }

how can i compare the value to valid because valid is [a] while value = a

Comment: Hi, are you using scripted or declarative pipeline? How are you passing the list to the job? What have you tried?

Comment: I used scripted.i try below but doesn't work.                                                            
   def list = [‘A’, ‘B’, ‘C’]
   def X= A
   println (list.contains(‘$X’)  
  currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'

Comment: Hopefully this will help, multiple things are discussed here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690920/conditional-step-stage-in-jenkins-pipeline